# How to get VisualStudio 2010 cool tools without spending $12,000

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devtools

We are a small dev shop with 10 people, 3 of whom are currently doing .Net. The new VisualStudio 2010 tools look really nice, and we would like to use them - but it seems that many of them (historical debugging, UML tools, testing stuff) are only going to be available in the Ultimate Edition. And that costs $12,000. Or nearly forty grand for the three of us.
(See [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/10/19/visual_studio_2010_second_beta_packaging/) for details).

Given that the architectural visualisation tools seem to be lifted straight from [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Purchase.aspx), which cost around €250 each (and is excellent), we just can't justify that sort of spending.

Now, we have a normal MSDN professional subscription, but that only got us one VS Team System, and I assume will not get us three 2010 Ultimates. Given that we have no use for the whole Team Foundation Server stuff, and just want the dev tools, what can we do?

EDIT:

Here is a list of the dev tools (leaving database and "testing lab" tools for another question) which are missing from the "Professional" version. An asterisk (*) means that the feature is in the "Premium" edition, no asterisk means only available in "Ultimate". What are the non-multi-thousand-dollar alternatives?

- **Testing:**

  Code Coverage   (*)

  Test Impact Analysis   (*)

  Coded UI Test   (*)

  Web Performance Testing

  Load Testing
- **Debugging & Diagnostics:**

  Static Code Analysis   (*)

  Code Metrics   (*)

  Profiling   (*)

  IntelliTrace (Historical Debugger)
- **Architecture and Modeling:**

  UML & Layer diagram viewer   (*)

  Architecture Explorer

  UML 2.0 Compliant Diagrams (Activity,
  Use Case, Sequence, Class, Component)

  Layer Diagram and Dependency
  Validation

Comment: You might add a list of the tools with their functionality to allow others to add their suggestions for alternatives. (I would not know in detail about the components of VSU2010)

Comment: good idea! I'll wait until I can find an official MS list of which tools are in which VS version.

Comment: You can find the the tools -> version information here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx#compare

Comment: From another standpoint, I'm interested in this because I'm interested in learning the stuff. My salary won't pay enough for even professional versions (for personal / educational use), so I'm stuck with express and whatever is free or incredibly cheap.

Answer (score 10):

If you're a small dev shop, Microsoft will give you the full version of VS (and then some) for a few years. Check out the [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) program.

Comment: Indeed, a "small dev shop" is precisely the target market for that campaign, and it all costs you $100 in 3 years if you don't end up making any significant money out of that ($1M annually is where you'll have to pay for the licenses in full - or drop out and pay $100 fee).

Comment: No, a small dev shop which is _less than 3 years old_ is the target market. As we have been going for closer 30 years than 3, no good for us I'm afraid...

Answer (score 8):

Like you've said, some of the tools are just copies of other tools that are already available in the market. If I were in your position I'd be looking at getting a version of Visual Studio that's covers all the basics a professional .net developer needs and then look at alternative tools. There are heaps of great open source and commercial tools that do an excellent job for free or for a reasonable price.

The best part about third party tools, in my opinion, is that they tend to be able to improve and adapt quicker than the standard Visual Studio release cycle. Things like continuous integration servers, unit testing frameworks, mocking/isolation frameworks, source control etc are often best done by third party tools so that as things change in the industry you can adapt your tools without having to wait for Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

Either you need the tools aand they'll pay for themselves in productivity. Or they are *a would like to have*. If the latter then you should consider what you absolute requirements are and start from there.

Besides 2010 isn't out yet so you have time to evaluate other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Look at volume licensing: It is cheaper for even one VS/MSDN licence, so should save significantly for three.

<s>Get VS 2008 Team Edition (e.g. Developer) with MSDN Premium today, and take advantage of the automatic upgrade to VS2010 Ultimate on its release.</s> *Removed*: offer applied before the VS2010 release.

Comment: This is what we actually did in the end. Our license costs have halved :O (and we managed to get a free upgrade, though that offer has expired afaik).

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it applies to your case, but have you checked the new Microsoft [WebSiteSpark program](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/24/announcing-the-websitespark-program.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need three seats, get one and share it for the toys?
I'm guessing that the entire team doesn't need to worry about architectural visualisation every day of course...

If you're really tight you could make the poor sods use Express most of the time as well.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For companies with Microsoft Partner status there is an option to get VSU for the same conditions enterprise customers get with volume licenses. However this starts with 20 licenses at roughly 20k€ every year for 3 years. (This could be limited to certain countries.)

Otherwise the typical recommendation would be to complement VS with

- NDepend
- Enterprise Architect (EA)
- some load test tool

There is no replacement for Intellitrace (which I wouldn't miss), Layer diagrams, test and lab management, that I'm aware of.

PS: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Answer (score 1):

To start off the alternatives, as mentioned above: [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Default.aspx) is an excellent alternative to the Architecture Explorer, though missing some of the integration into VS. It also provides Code Metrics (dozens of them!) and static code analysis, including flagging dependency cycles etc etc.

Costs around €250 for the full version; there is a free academic/trial version.

Comment: NDepend v3 is 100% integrated in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it.... if you upgrade to an MSDN premium subscription and you currently have VS.NET 2008 professional and/or 2008 TS before March 22nd 2010 you will get ultimate upgrade for FREE.  My source is the following article

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/10/19/visual_studio_2010_second_beta_packaging/

Edit: The info is located near the end of the article.  Sounds like a pretty good deal to me!

Answer (score 0):

1) do without

2) find alternatives

3) lobby MS (you probably won't be alone in this) for standalone versions

You can't always get the tools you want at the price you want. We're in a similar boat :(

Answer (score 0):

use **[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)** and hope that they will implement those features as soon as possible...

Comment: It will probably be a long time before SharpDevelop has implemented all the new VS 2010 features.
But I hope I'm wrong.